# Eslint Error while working with Trails js

Tags: javascript, eslint, gulp-eslint, trailsjs

I am using Eslint to lint the code of my Trails.js project before testing it. Tails.js comes with existing pre-configurations [eslint-config-trails](https://github.com/trailsjs/eslint-config-trails). However, when I am testing my code eslint throws a `Definition for rule 'no-global-assign' was not found` error, for every .js file in my codebase.

Manually adding the rule:

```
"rules": {
  "no-global-assign": ["error", {"exceptions": ["Object"]}]
}
```

Doesn't fix the error. Setting the rule to `"warn"` makes me at least run the tests, but outputs a warning for every .js file.

Comment: i think u are using an older version of eslint

Comment: I am using version 2.13.1

Comment: upgrade to 3.0 ds

Comment: Version 3.0 didn't work. I updated to the latest (v4.10.0). It is working with this version now. Thank you!

Comment: no problem :)p good

Answer (score 0):

The `no-global-assign` rule was [added in ESLint 3.3.0](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

You need to use that version or later, if you want to use that rule.